# Password Expired on Server 2008 R2

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, domain-controller, password-recovery

We're facing some trouble with our Windows Server 2008 R2 installation.

The passwords expired and we're prompted to change the password.

After changing it, we get following error message:

`Configuration Information could no be read from the domain controller, either because the machine is unavailable, or access has been denied.`

But we aren't even using a `domain controller`.

So we tried running the server in `Safe Mode` where we get following message after changing the password:

`An attempt was made to logon, but the network logon service was not started.`

Are there any other things I could try?

All help is more than appreciated!

Comment: Is this the password for the service account which has expired?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's working now!

Solution:

We got it to work by just rolling back the `BIOS` clock.

This has reset the password expiration date and everything worked like a charm!

Thanks for all the help!

Answer (score 0):

More context needed.

- Single server, no domain you say
- Have you tried a restart?
- Have you tried WAITING after server start? It can take some minutes until the SAM is loaded and the local passwords are available.
- What is the server name, what do you enter into the user name field? Not interested in the password - just validating there really is no domain involved.

Comment: - Yes, it's a single server
- Several times, no difference
- Well, we made it so that the server does logon automatically - therefore we are prompted to change the password every time
- The user is selected by default already, - due to auto logon

-> is there a way to logon using the administrator account?

Comment: No idea then, too. never do auto logon - dont know it like that. After logon failure you should sort of be able to log in manually, or?

Comment: I thought the same. It doesn't allow you to change the user...

Comment: Hate to say so... happy reinstallation. You got a password recovery disc? if not.... next time you have.

Sucks, but I also have no idea what else to do.

Comment: Found out, how to do it. Wasn't that hard :-], no reinstallation required.

Answer (score 0):

Are you not able to F8 during reboot and go safe mode or safe mode command line, then remove auto logon? (roll back on restore point perhaps?)

Auto logon to a server seems like a bad idea... if you have stuff you need to run automatically, then run it as a service: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/137890

How about loggin on remotly via RDP? Could easily specify administrator then.

Guess you could try using a password hack disc as a last resort, or mount the HD in a different box (could be hard if it is rack server). I use one regularly on non-domain deadlocked clients.

GLHF :)

Comment: Thanks for your answer.

Even loggin in in safe mode with command prompt didn't work -> it required the password first.

Comment: It was very easy, provided the answer / solution as an answer here :-)